# How to request multiple properties in Sharepoint 2013 restful api?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest

In sharepoint 2013 resful api, I am using this

```
mysite/_api/sp.userprofiles.peoplemanager/getuserprofilepropertyfor(accountname=@v, propertyname='testprop1')?@v='aq/hello'
```

to get custom user properties, that I can't get in the standard way to call resful api for properties.

But in this type of api call, how can I specify multiple properties, I tried

```
mysite/_api/sp.userprofiles.peoplemanager/getuserprofilepropertyfor(accountname=@v, propertyname='testprop1, testprop2')?@v='aq/hello'
```

but it didn't work... Does anyone know a way?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned here in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163800.aspx), There are two functions in SP to get the properties

```
getUserProfilePropertiesFor // for multiple properties, not  availablee in REST
GetUserProfilePropertyFor   // for single property
```

MSDN documentation has clearly stated that the "getUserProfilePropertiesFor" method is not implemented in REST (search for 'getUserProfilePropertiesFor' without quotes in that page). So, unfortunately you can only load one property at a time